# How to better define $f(n)=\begin{cases} 1,&n\text{ even} \\ 0, &n\text{ odd}\end{cases}$?

Tags: functions

How to define $f(n)=\begin{cases} 1,&n\text{ even} \\ 0, &n\text{ odd}\end{cases},n\in\mathbb N$ using common functions like ceiling or floor, or other?

Thanks.

Comment: How about $\displaystyle n-2\left\lceil \frac n2\right\rceil +1$?

Comment: That's probably the best definition ever.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function you describe is perfectly adequate. But sometimes, ask and you shall receive.

Any periodic function can be written succinctly as a sum over the characters with conductor equal to that period. This is a high level way of saying that we should use $(-1)^n$ and $1^n = 1$ in some way.

Notice that
$$ f(n) = \frac{1 + (-1)^n}{2}$$
is a different way of writing the function that you want.

Answer (score 2):

There are many options.  For example:

$$f(n) = 0.5 + 0.5\cdot(-1)^n$$

and

$$f(n) = 0.5 + 0.5\cos(\pi n)$$

Answer (score 1):

$f(n) = (n+1) \pmod 2$ or $f(n) = (n+1) - 2 \times \lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\rfloor$

Answer (score 1):

I think $$f(n)= \cos^2 \frac{n\pi}{2}$$ does the trick, as does $$f(n)=\left|\cos\frac{n\pi}{2}\right|$$

Answer (score 1):

Where $2\mathbb{Z} = \{\dots, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, \dots, \}$, you could do $$f(n) = \mathbf{1}_{2\mathbb{Z}}(n)\text{, } n \in \mathbb{Z}\text{.}$$